# Remove username validate createuserwizard

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, createuserwizard

I'm building a login and register page for a website with Asp.Net
In login page have a popup register form.
A problem in this is : I wanna use my validate for user but I cannot disable validator of CreateUserWizard.
1/ How can I turn off the Validator ? It doesnt work nice.
2/ If I have a textbox or another component in Wizard Template (ex : a textbox in ContentTemplate of CreateUserWizard. How can I call that textbox in my code ? I dont wanna use question and anwser box. I wanna use a new field but I can't call it in my code.
Thanks and sorry for my English

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard2" runat="server">
                    <WizardSteps>
                        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep2" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                            Sign Up for Your New Account</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                                ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="ConfirmPasswordLabel" runat="server" 
                                                AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm Password:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="ConfirmPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ConfirmPasswordRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                                ErrorMessage="Confirm Password is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Confirm Password is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="EmailRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Email" ErrorMessage="E-mail is required." 
                                                ToolTip="E-mail is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="QuestionLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Question">Security Question:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Question" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="QuestionRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Question" ErrorMessage="Security question is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Security question is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <asp:Label ID="AnswerLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Answer">Security Answer:</asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="Answer" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="AnswerRequired" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToValidate="Answer" ErrorMessage="Security answer is required." 
                                                ToolTip="Security answer is required." ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PasswordCompare" runat="server" 
                                                ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword" 
                                                Display="Dynamic" 
                                                ErrorMessage="The Password and Confirmation Password must match." 
                                                ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard2"></asp:CompareValidator>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:Red;">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="ErrorMessage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
                        <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep2" runat="server">
                        </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
                    </WizardSteps>
                </asp:CreateUserWizard>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wizards a generally that - closed wizards.  You can easily create your own login / registration using the membership classes as exposed in code.  Then you have full control over them.

Comment: Thanks for ur support. I created a new form and controlled it ^^

Comment: Excellent.  They are very nice "starting" controls, to get your project at least started, then a person can "replace" those forms as the need arises.

Comment: Remember to mark as answered - if it has solved your problem.